# Will this Capybara test flake?

Tags: javascript, rspec, capybara, capybara-webkit, poltergeist

When using capybara-webkit or poltergeist to test JavaScript behavior, I often find (or unfortunately, write) tests that look like this

```
it "saves the check box value when clicked", js: true do
  visit '/somewhere'

  page.should have_unchecked_field 'cool_check_box'

  page.check 'cool_check_box'

  visit '/somewhere'

  page.should have_checked_field 'cool_check_box'
end
```

... where checking the checkbox makes some AJAX request that saves whatever state allows it to be checked after a quick reload.

That test seems guaranteed to flake, because if the AJAX request doesn't complete by the time the second `visit '/somewhere'` happens, it will load with the checkbox in the wrong state.

Luckily on this page there's also a spinner that spins along while the checkbox request is completing, so I can amend the test like so

```
it "saves the check box value when clicked", js: true do
  visit '/somewhere'

  page.should have_unchecked_field 'cool_check_box'

  page.check 'cool_check_box'

  # Wait for checkbox ajax to complete
  page.should have_css('.spinner:not(.active)')

  visit '/somewhere'

  page.should have_checked_field 'cool_check_box'
end
```

I'm still a little paranoid, though: if the `page.check` line ran but didn't manage to set the spinner as `active` before the `page.should have_css` line, that line would succeed before the request even started.

Given that the JavaScript triggered by the checkbox sets the `active` class, can I guarantee this test will never flake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're talking about is the risk of the code that handles the check event running *concurrently* to the code which checks for `.spinner:not(.active)`. This is not a risk since the Javascript on the page is single-threaded - you can guarantee that the check even will be handled first.